# viewWillAppear in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to stream video from the camera in a View with React Native. The problem is, if the user presses the home button, temporarily leave the app and switch back, the stream URL will be changed.

So I need to update the URL in a function similar to `viewWillAppear` as in native iOS framework. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: I'm thinking of using AppState to track the state of the app. Still wonder if there is better a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes @Danny Want is right you can use `AppState`. It can be used like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    currentAppState: AppState.currentState,
  };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
_handleAppStateChange: function(currentAppState) {
  this.setState({ currentAppState, });
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <Text>Current state is: {this.state.currentAppState}</Text>
  );
},
```

Do what you wanna do in the `AppState` handler: `_handleAppStateChange`. For more details please check out [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html)

Comment: This will not be enough if you want to watch view visibility of element while the app is active (eg. inside scrollview view can be visible or not)