# How to handle `viewWillAppear` after react-navigation's tab is selected?

Tags: react-native

I have something like this, is this possible to have something like viewWillAppear in the React Native's world? Thanks.:

```
MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      'Profile': {
        screen: Profile
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [viewWillAppear in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433020/viewwillappear-in-react-native)